# why is this fastai.tabular regression not working?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, tabular, fast-ai

Im trying to do a regression problem with 1500 rows but it’s not working for some reason. If anyone can tell me what I’m doing wrong, that would be really helpful.
This is my code:

```
data = (TabularList.from_df(train, path=’.’, cat_names=cat_names, cont_names=cont_names, procs=procs)
.split_by_idx(list(range(1200,1500)))
.label_from_df(cols = dep_var, label_cls=FloatList)
.add_test(test, label=0)
.databunch())
```

Create deep learning model

```
learn = tabular_learner(data, layers=[200,100], metrics=rmse,
ps=[0.001,0.01], emb_drop=0.02,
callback_fns=ShowGraph)

learn.lr_find()
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX1lX.png)

```
learn.recorder.plot()
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVXko.png)

```
learn.fit_one_cycle(10, max_lr=slice(3e-02), wd=0.1)
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0WvV.png)